# How do I animate div with background image along curved path but stop at X percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I have been able to animate a div with a background image as well as resize it along the path.  However, I am trying to get this CSS-based animation to stop at a certain percentage of the progress.

The premise is to visually show a student her/his progress of completing a varying number of tasks (8 of 12 complete. 68%).  That is not a problem with a straight progress bar, but I am looking to use an image of a mountain with a hiker moving along a path.  I can get the hiker image from start to end with the following code, but I need it to stop based on the progress of the student.

I am trying to keep this as simple as I can, but do not have to use CSS.

```css
.mtnBg
{
    height:306px;
    width:450px;
    border:1px silver solid;
    background-image: url(https://comps.canstockphoto.com/mountain-with-trail-and-sun-retro-style-eps-vector_csp43572145.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    display:block;
    opacity:.18;
    z-index:-1;
}


.animSurround {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:140px;
    bottom:50px;
    border:1px none black;
    animation: yAxis 2.8s 1 ease;

}
.anim {
    background-image: url(https://www.tenstickers.co.uk/wall-stickers/img/preview/hiker-icon-sticker-8451.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height:32px;
    min-width:32px;
    background-size: 100%;
    animation-iteration-count:1;
    animation: zoom-move 2.8s ease 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.anim::after {
    /* Render dot, and animate along Y-axis */
    min-height:96px;
    min-width:96px;
}


@keyframes zoom-move {
  0% {
    transform: scale(3) translateX(calc(0px)) translateY(0px);
    opacity: 0.50;
    border-radius:32px;
    background-color: rgba(256 , 256, 256, 1);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(2.6) translateX(60px) translateY(-19px);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius:32px;
    background-color: rgba(256 , 256, 256, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.7) translateX(68px) translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius:32px;
    background-color: rgba(256 , 256, 256, 1); 
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
  93% {
    background-color: rgba(256 , 256, 256, 1);
  }
  99% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(161px) translateY(-122px);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius:32px;
    background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(161px) translateY(-122px);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius:32px;
    background-color: rgba(76, 175, 80, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mtnBg"></div>
<div class="animSurround">
    <div class="anim"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't really stop a CSS animation dynamically at a certain percentage I think. I wonder if you could break your animation up into smaller "steps" (assigning each animation step a css class)  and apply the appropriate classes depending on how far the student makes it. But this might be a pain to manage... like if you added more steps (going from completing 8 of 12 to 8 of 15 for example). SVG might be a good option here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the `animation-play-state` property. The is idea to convert the % value to the time when the animation should be paused. So you using JS/jQuery you run the animation and after this amount of time you set the property `animation-play-state`:

Here is an example with a simplied animation:

```js
/* if we want the animation to run until 10%
   we consider a duratioon of Xs and we should run until 0.1 * Xs

   The duration will only affect the speed
   so use a small value to simulate an instant change.
*/

var duration = 3;

function stop_animation(element, percent) {
  var stop = (percent / 100) * duration; /* we get the value un second*/
  stop *= 1000 /* we transform to milliseconds */
  element.css('animation', 'anim ' + duration + 's linear');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
  }, stop);
}

stop_animation($('.element').eq(0),50);
stop_animation($('.element').eq(1),20);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 10%, transparent 11%) 0 0/20px 100%;
}

.element {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Thank you.  I am now setting percentage of completed items from a SQL select statement and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @Espresso_J great :)